# remove li from div using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am adding items in a div that is dragged by an other div now i want that when item is drag from selected item div if it is in the same div then it revert back or sorted but if we drag from selected item div and drop from some where else then it also remove from the selected item div

basically i want to add remove option after selecting an item

for better understanding this is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qyZ8/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    items = $('#items');
    selection = $('#selection');

    // selected items is sortable also

    selection.sortable({
        item: "li",
        containment: "document"
    });

//above div dragable
$('#items  li').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    containment: "document",
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
 });    

//below div dropable
selection.droppable({
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "<li class='sortable-item' data-name='"+ui.draggable.attr('data-name')+"'></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo(selection);

    }
}).sortable({
    items: "li",
    containment: "document"
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think its what you want. You were creating a new li from the selected one. I think you want to detach it and append it to the bottom div. Even if you have data attached to the element you will keep it and you don't have to worry about data-name problems.

```
//below div dropable
    selection.droppable({
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(ui.draggable).detach().appendTo(selection);
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li",
        containment: "document"
    });
```

Comment: i have a scenario in which a user select items from above div and drop into below div only copy of li from above div is added into below div.but now i want to remove elements from below div when it is dragged and drop out outside the below div